# Creating and returning a copy of the same object

Tags: java, copy, this, clone

In this class `Coord` the method `public Coord copy()` should create and return a new Coord value with the same row/column representation as the current object. Why is it giving me error when I make `this = clone` ?

```
public class Coord {

    public final int r;
    public final int c;


    public Coord(int r, int c)
    {
        this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Coord step(Direction d)
    {
        if(d == Direction.N)
        {
            Coord newValue = new Coord(r + 1, c);
            return newValue;
        }
        else if(d == Direction.S)
        {
            Coord newValue = new Coord(r - 1, c);
            return newValue;
        }
        else if(d == Direction.E)
        {
            Coord newValue = new Coord(r, c + 1);
            return newValue;
        }
        else if(d == Direction.W)
        {
            Coord newValue = new Coord(r, c - 1);
            return newValue;
        }

        else
            return this;

    }

    public Coord copy()
    {
        Coord clone = new Coord(r, c);
        this = clone;
        return clone;

    }


}
```

Comment: Have  a search for `copy constructors`, that sounds like a good pattern for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do this instead:

```
public Coord copy() {
    Coord clone = new Coord(r, c);
    return clone;
}
```

In this case, it could even be shortened to:

```
public Coord copy() {
    return new Coord(r, c);
}
```

The [`this` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is a reference to the current object (in this case, the current `Coord` object), and Java won't allow you to assign a new value to `this`.  If you want to make a copy, then you just need to create your new object and return that new object.

---

Maybe it will help to think of it like this.

You are probably using `Coord`'s `copy()` method in a manner such as this to make a copy:

```
int x = ...; //x is some int
int y = ...; //y is some int

Coord coordOriginal = new Coord(x, y);
//coordOriginal points to a new Coord object. Let's call it "A".

Coord coordCopy = coordOriginal.copy();
//coordCopy points to to a new Coord object.  Let's call it "B".
//coordOriginal still points to Coord object "A".
```

If `copy()` is working correctly, you would expect `coordOriginal` and `coordCopy` to point to **two different** objects.  `coordOriginal` points to `Coord` object *A*, and `coordCopy` points to `Coord` object *B*.

Now let's pretend that you can assign a new value to `this` as in your sample code's `copy()` method:

```
//in this case, "this" points to object "A".
public Coord copy()
{
    //creates an object "B"
    Coord clone = new Coord(r, c);

    //***overwrites object "A" with object "B"!***
    this = clone;

    //returns object "B"
    return clone;
}
//object "A" gets garbage collected?
```

So you see, if you could assign a new object to `this` (and Java won't let you) inside your `copy()` method, you would be changing the original `Coord` object when all you wanted to do was make a copy!

---

As stated in the question comments, another approach is to make a copy constructor:

```
public class Coord {

    public final int r;
    public final int c;

    public Coord(int r, int c) {
        this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
    }

    //copy constructor
    public Coord(Coord other) {
        this(other.r, other.c);
    }

}
```

Then you can make a copy like this:

```
int x = ...; //x is some int
int y = ...; //y is some int

Coord coordOriginal = new Coord(x, y);
Coord coordCopy = new Coord(coordOriginal);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `this` is a keyword and not a variable, so assigning to a keyword doesn't make sense.

In second instance you can't assign to `this` because in Java it is forbidden, `this` refers to the object on which you are calling the current method and, although it could be technically possible, it is not allowed.

To obtain the same thing you must reassign where the object is stored to the new created `Coord` from outside the method, or by accessing the container. An alternative would be to directly modify the member variables of the object itself but it is not the same thing.

Comment: what do you mean by "To obtain the same thing you must reassign where the object is stored to the new created Coord from outside the method, or by accessing the container." ?